# cannot import name AdaBoostClassifier

Tags: scikit-learn

Using the scikit learn library (0.13.1) successfully in Python 2.7 on Ubuntu with RandomTreeClassifier, ExtraTree loading successfully, but cannot get AdaBoost to load, receiving IMportError: cannot import name AdaBoost.  Relatively new to linux and package install in general, but have somewhat gathered that maybe AdaBoost or a dependency did not compile/ build correctly.  Any assistance appreciated, cannot find anything similar via google search or this forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AdaBoostClassifier is currently available only in the development branch that will lead to the 0.14 release at some point in the future, see the global changelog:

http://scikit-learn.org/dev/whats_new.html#changes-0-14